# Most used tendertype per store T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help building this MSSQL Query.
I have a table with payment info.
In the table  "payment_entry" is a field for Storenumber and Tendertype.
Every new purchase creates a new line in the table "payment_entry" with "store" and "tendertype".
There are two tendertypes "1" or "3". 
1 means credit/debit card and 3 means cash.

I want a query that groups by store how many percent of the customers in each store pays cash and how many pays by card.

Thanks in advance!!
EDIT: 
Well im no good at SQL but this gave me a count per store for tendertype 1.. Now im stuck..

```
Select [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_], 
Count([company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Tender Type]) 
From [company$Trans_ Payment Entry] [company$Trans_ Payment Entry] 
Where [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Tender Type] = '1' 
Group By [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_] 
Order By [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_]
```

Comment: Well im no good at SQL but this gave me a count per store for tendertype 1.. Now im stuck..

Select [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_],
  Count([company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Tender Type])
From
    [company$Trans_ Payment Entry]
    [company$Trans_ Payment Entry]
Where [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Tender Type] = '1'
Group By [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_]
Order By [company$Trans_ Payment Entry].[Store No_]

Comment: Good grief those table and column names would make me want to kill myself. How about putting a MAX around your count.

Comment: Haha It's Microsoft dynamics tables, that's Microsoft for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH Store_Totals AS
 (
  SELECT [Store No_] AS StoreNum
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN tendertypes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Credit_Trans
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN tendertypes = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cash_Trans
        ,COUNT(tendertypes)  AS Total_Trans
  FROM [company$Trans_ Payment Entry]
  GROUP BY [Store No_]
 )
SELECT  StoreNum
       ,Credit_Trans / Total_Trans AS Average_Credit
       ,Cash_Trans   / Total_Trans AS Average_Cash
FROM Store_Totals
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with CASE based aggregation

```
SELECT store, 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN tendertype =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100.0/COUNT(tenderType)) AS CreditPerc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tendertype =3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100.0/COUNT(tenderType) as CashPerc
FROM payment_entry
GROUP BY store
```